# Remove outlier from grouped data

Tags: r, quantile

I have a data frame as following:

```
ID Value
A   70
A   80
B   75
C   10
B   50
A   100
C   60
..  ..
```

I would like to group this data by ID, remove the outliers from the grouped data (the ones we see from the boxplot) and then calculate mean.

So far I have done the followin:

```
#Summary before removing outliers
summaryBy(Value ~ ID, data = df, FUN = c(mean, median, sd))

df_quantile = do.call("rbind", tapply(df$Value, df$ID, quantile))

filtered = function(x) {
   lowerq = quantile(x)[2]
   upperq = quantile(x)[4]
   iqr = upperq - lowerq

   mild.threshold.upper = (iqr * 1.5) + upperq
   mild.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 1.5)

   extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
   extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)

   x = x[x > extreme.threshold.lower & x < extreme.threshold.upper]
   return(x)
}

filtData = tapply(df$Value, df$ID, filtered)
```

**Once I remove the outliers, how do I apply mean, sd on the `filtData`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your provided data includes no outliers in a boxplot I used some R data:
You can save the boxplot, get the outliers, remove them and plot again, or calculate the mean per group.

```
n <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, boxwex=0.25)
InsectSprays_without_outlier <- InsectSprays[-which(InsectSprays$count %in% n$out & InsectSprays$spray %in% c("C","D")), ]
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays_without_outlier, add=T, col=2, at =1:nlevels(InsectSprays$spray) + 0.2, boxwex=0.25)
# mean value per group
aggregate(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays_without_outlier, mean)
```

**Edit:** A more general solution. 
There must be a more elegant way but you can try this:

```
# the boxplot to get the stat
n <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays,boxwex=0.25)
# make a list of your data per group
a <- split(InsectSprays, InsectSprays$spray)
# Go through the list and exclude the outliers
a <- lapply(1:nlevels(InsectSprays$spray), function(i,x) 
  subset(x[[i]], count <= n$stats[5, i] & count >= n$stats[1, i]), a)
# Transform to a data.frame again
InsectSprays_without_outlier <- do.call(rbind, a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I was looking for. But how do I apply generally, if I do not know which Group has outliers. For example, assuming, I do not know that group C & D has outliers. The thing is, the ID in my case is very long and I cant do it manually.